# Muliple patch in Python unitest not working

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

My test case looks like this. Following is the code:

```
@patch('something.mysqlclient')
@patch('something.esclient')
def testcase1(mysql,esclient):
    esclient.return_value = 1
    mysql.return_value = 3
    assert something.modeul1.esclient == 1
    assert something.modeul1.mysql == 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorator works from bottom to top.

```
@patch('something.mysqlclient')
@patch('something.esclient')
def testcase1(esclient, mysql):
    pass
```